# Сode hints in PhpStorm

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, code-completion

How to configure PhpStorm so that when coding a PHP project in Laravel to automatically display code completion popup, otherwise you have to constantly press <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd>... and only then do the hints appear...

[image: Screenshot:]

Answer (score 0):

You can also try install PHP Storm plugins name

- Symfony Support - https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7219-symfony-support
- Laravel Plugin - https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7532-laravel

These are the plugin use, and it provides all the Support for Laravel, and symfony for auto completion.

You can go to settings, and plugins, and search these plugins, it will surely help you for all your needs.

Make sure, you restart PHP Storm, after you install the plugins